# How do you plot a function without a y-axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm looking to design a question where students sketch a derivative based on a drawn function without the y-axis.

The y-axis is not important as we're focusing on the x-values of turning points and inflection points (in fact I don't need it at all).

I haven't managed to find a way to graph a function with only the x-axis (without the ticks or numbers is even better) with tikz or pgfplots.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 13):

What you're looking for is `axis y line=none`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=none,
      domain=-360:360,
      xtick={-360, -330, ..., 360},
      samples=1001,
      xticklabels=\empty,
    ]
    \addplot [red!80!black] {sin(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: @Jonopan If this answer has resolved your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).