# pgfplots: How do I manually change xtick labels (a letter instead of a number)?

Tags: pgfplots

The below picture is what I have currently: what I want is to change `4` to `a` and `6` to `b`; but, if I change one of them using the `xticklabel` option it globally changes all `x-values` to that value. There's also the issue of the `xtick` height; if you see below, it goes way above the normal distribution--I tried some of the options in the "Tick-Fine Tuning" section in the manual, but they didn't work for me. I'm also trying to remove the `y-axis`: one thing I tried is messing around with the `axis lines*=left` option; however I wasn't able to come up with the result I wanted.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, domain=0:10, samples=100,
  axis lines*=left,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=3cm, width=6cm, 
  xtick={4, 6}, ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
  grid = major
  ]
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=4:6] {gauss(5,1)} \closedcycle;
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, I would also like to have another normal distribution in the same row: I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: Please limit your posts to one question per post, I provide an answer to the question about changing the x tick label from 4 to a etc.

Comment: Thanks for the good MWE (but you can remove several of the options for the question).

Comment: About removing the `y axis`, there are several related question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296325 (`axis y line=none`) for example (I googled `pgfplots remove y axis`).

Comment: I also removed `for normal distribution` from your title because it is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Thank you for the help that related question solved the y-axis removal for me. @Dr.ManuelKuehner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Using `xticklabels = {\strut a, \strut b},` leads to the following output (see also the two comments in the code). You can use `$a$` instead of `a` if that is more appropriate for your use case.
- You have to be careful, there is an option called `xticklabel` and
  another one called `xticklabels` (with "s").
- This caused confusion
  for myself in the past :).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % <-- ADDED, see Warning Message "Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} into your preamble."
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  no markers, 
  domain=0:10, 
  samples=100,
  axis lines*=left,
  every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
  every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
  height=3cm, 
  width=6cm, 
  xtick={4, 6}, 
  xticklabels = {\strut a, \strut b}, % <-- ADDED, the \strut makes that both labels have the same height
  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=false, 
  clip=false, 
  axis on top,
  grid = major,
  ]
  \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=4:6] {gauss(5,1)} \closedcycle;
  \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(5,1)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```